# Supposed to or Have to for obligations

Tags: grammar, word-choice, vocabulary, modal-verbs

I can't settle an argument with myself about the difference between "Supposed to" and "Have to". For instance

> Kids' show *are supposed to have* simple language

Or

> Kids'show *have to have* simple language

What's the difference?